# How can I reach image of itemtemplate in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemtemplate

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="listBox" Background="#2e2e2e" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,71.8,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel Background="#1f1f1f" Height="150" Width="1169" MouseEnter="listBox_Selected" MouseLeave="listBox_Unselected" MouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <Image Name="listImg" Source="{Binding image}" Width="120" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="19" Margin="132,-140,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="#FFABAAAA" Text="{Binding comment}" FontSize="17" Margin="132,-90,0,0" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding username}" FontFamily="Poetsen One" FontSize="13" Margin="130,-25,0,0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="CornflowerBlue" Text="{Binding cost}" FontSize="16" Margin="1080,-30,0,0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding id}" FontSize="15" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I can't reach `listImg`.

I have to use it when I select the listbox item.

How can I reach it in code above?

Comment: *"I have to use it …"* - for what reason exactly? While it is possible to access it in code behind, it is virtually never necessary.

Comment: I want to use source of that image.When I select any item in listbox,a new window opens , so I want to use source of the image to add image to new window.However I didn't reach the image source :/

Comment: You would get that by casting the ListBox's SelectedItem to your item type, and then access its `image` property. In a proper MVVM approach you would *bind* SelectedItem to a view model property and get the image from the selected item in the view model.

Comment: I wrote this , but it didn't work :/ 
anyImage=(Image)listBox.SelectedItem;
How should I search this issue in google ? any keywords ?

Comment: That's not what I suggested. You didn't show us how your view model item class (the class with the `image` property) looks like, but let's call it `MyItem`. Then you could write `var image = ((MyItem)SelectedItem).image` to get the binding source property.

Comment: My class name is Products , and I wrote this 
var image = ((Products)listBox.SelectedItem).image;

but vs threw an exception that is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Certainly because SelectedItem is null. You should of course check that before.

Comment: Already I check that selected item is null , but I can't reach it :/

if(image!=null)
{
 var image = ((Products)listBox.SelectedItem).image;
}

Comment: `if (image != null)` is not the same as `if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)` ?!

Comment: But listbox.SelectedItem always returns null

Comment: Not when you select a listbox item, as you said you do.

Comment: Even though I select a listbox item it returns null , so if(listbox.SelectedItem != null) never works

Comment: I solved the problem,thank you so much :)